# Android Barcode Scanner API - Target host must not be null, or set in parameters

Tags: java, android, qr-code

I was making an app in Android for scanning QR Codes, and with some tutorials, I reached this code:

```
Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detector.detect(frame);
if (barcodes.size() < 1) {
  Debug("Scan Failed: Found nothing to scan");
} else {
  Barcode code = barcodes.valueAt(0);
  String value = code.displayValue;
  Parse(value);
}
```

When I call it, it shows me this error:

```
E/Barcode Scanner API: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=data1
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I would need more context to debug this but.. If you just want to get up and running fast maybe [this link](https://www.varvet.com/blog/android-qr-code-reader-made-easy/) will help. It has all the camera and barcode classes all set up, using Google's vision api. Just go from there.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it